# How to find available Item On a particular date or on particular period of time

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project named 'rental system'(java). for a shop where items are available on rent.In maintaining DB(Using MYSQL), i am following tables:-

customer table:-

```
C_ID --C_Name--C_ADD--C_contactNo
1    -- abc  --Add1 --XXXXXXXXX
2    -- xyz  --Add2 --xxxxxxxxx
3    -- pqr  --Add3 --xxxxxxxxx
```

---

```
Item table:-
Item_ID --Item_Name --Total_qty
1       --chair     --200  
2       --pillow    --500
3       --sofa_large--100
4       --Bedshits  --600
5       --Wedsofa   --50
6       --chair_A   --150
```

---

```
Cus_Order_tab :-

O_ID -- C_ID--venue --startdate       --enddate
1    --  2  -- xyz  --2012-03-03 4:30 --2012-03-04 2:30
2    --  3  -- pqr  --2012-03-03 12:01--2012-03-07 6:00
3    --  2  -- xyz  --2012-03-04 11:00--2012-03-09 5:00
4    --  1  -- ijk  --2012-03-04 12:33--2012-03-05 7:30
```

---

```
Item_order_tab:-
O_ID --Item_ID -- Ordred_qty
1    --2       --   100
1    --3       --   50
1    --4       --   350
2    --1       --   75
2    --4       --   200
2    --3       --   30
3    --1       --   100
4    --4       --   50 
4    --2       --   150
```

---

with this i want to find item available on a particular date or for a particular period of time.For example consider i 've O_ID= 5 on date startdate='2012-03-04 2:30' enddate='2012-03-05 3:30'and for this i want to see itemList which is available on this period in following formate:-

---

ItemName  --   Availble_qty

chair     --           ?

sofalarge --           ?

pillow    --           ?

Bedshits  --           ?

wedsofa   --           ?

chair_A   --           ?

---

Comment: What have you got so far and is this homework?

Comment: no,can u help me to find any solution ASAP...

Answer (score 1):

When posting on any forum it is a good idea to at least make an attempt at what you require instead of simply asking for the answer. We are not all sat around waiting to do your job for you.

That said, this should get you started but will need some tweaking to deal with thresholds between hires due to the use of hours instead of minutes -

```
# This outermost query finds the minimum num of each product available
# for the time period defined in the order
#EXPLAIN
SELECT
    tmp2.item_id,
    tmp2.item_name,
    MIN(tmp2.num_available) AS num_available
FROM (
    # This query left joins to the innermost derived table
    # to find out how many of each product is available
    # for each hour
    SELECT
        tmp.item_id,
        tmp.item_name,
        tmp.chour,
        tmp.item_quantity - IFNULL(SUM(io.ordered_quantity), 0) AS num_available
    FROM (
        # This inner query is to retrieve every possible
        # hour for each product within the order's period
        SELECT
            i.item_id,
            i.item_name,
            co.startdate + INTERVAL th.h HOUR chour,
            i.item_quantity
        FROM item i
        INNER JOIN temp_hours th
        INNER JOIN cus_order co
            ON HOUR(TIMEDIFF(co.enddate, co.startdate)) >= th.h
        WHERE co.o_id = 5
    ) AS tmp
    LEFT JOIN cus_order co2
        ON tmp.chour BETWEEN co2.startdate AND co2.enddate
    LEFT JOIN item_order io
        ON co2.o_id = io.o_id
        AND tmp.item_id = io.item_id
    GROUP BY
        tmp.item_id,
        tmp.item_name,
        tmp.chour
) AS tmp2
GROUP BY
    tmp2.item_id,
    tmp2.item_name
```

Use of appropriate indices will be very important to get good performance with this.  You will need to populate a temp_hours(h INT) table with a contiguous set from 0 to whatever your max hire period is in hours.  So, if your max hire period is one month you should create a contiguous set from 0 to (31 * 24).

Comment: What is wrong with the query I have written? Please add your CREATE TABLE statements to your original question along with the output of `SHOW INDEXES` for each of the tables involved.